# Istanbul in 3 days; is there an Istanbul Pass?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, sightseeing, istanbul

I'll be staying in Istanbul for three days. Is there any Pass that grants access to most places worth visiting and, perhaps, public transport?

Comment: I removed the opinion based question from the post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Yes there is!](http://bfy.tw/vUW)

Witt Hotels has some excellent information on Istanbul, which I have personally used and recommend reading.  I have not used the Istanbul tourist pass or Museum pass myself as I did not deem it worthwhile for myself and based on the 'attractions' I wanted to see.

- [Istanbul Museum Pass](http://www.wittistanbul.com/magazine/what-is-the-istanbul-museum-pass-and-should-i-get-one/)
- [Public Transport](http://www.wittistanbul.com/magazine/use-public-transportation-in-istanbul-to-reach-most-places-of-interest/)
- [Istanbul Kart](http://www.wittistanbul.com/magazine/how-to-get-an-istanbul-kart-and-is-it-worth-it/) for public transport

To clarify, there are two passes, an [Istanbul Museum Card](https://www.muze.gov.tr/buy_museum_pass) and an [Istanbul Tourist Pass](http://www.istanbultouristpass.com/)

The tourist passes have options to add public transport.

**[Essential Pass](http://www.istanbultouristpass.com/essential-classic/)**

Adult $75.00 USD, Child (Age 2-12) $35.00 USD

**[Flexible Pass](http://www.istanbultouristpass.com/flexible/)**

Adult $200.00 USD, Child (Age 2-12) $140.00 USD

**Updated with recommendation:**

Get the 3 day Museum Pass for 85TL and Istanbul Kart to get around. Its cheaper and the additional "attractions" on the tourist pass are quite tourist oriented and may be marked up a bit.  You can definitely get cheaper local alternatives for the cruise/ferry etc.